# Driver.manage().timeouts() is not available

Tags: webdriver

Using the latest `jar` of webdriver `java(2.33)`, trying to set implicit wait but the `timeouts()` is not available in available options for `driver.manage()` in `Eclipse`.

It throws an error that this is not an available option for this class. Tried the same with `2.30` and same issue was repeating. Has any one seen such issue, please let me know on how this can be handled?

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Not available, in the sense, eclipse is not showing the timeouts() method? what is the error that eclipse is throwing when you are directly writing the below code?

`WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Comment: Yes the method is not listed in intellisense. And the error is - The method timeouts() is undefined for the type WebDriver.Options

Comment: There is one more issue i have noticed is the isDisplayed() for WebElement is not coming up in intellisense.

Comment: Just a confirmation. Does your code include the below import statements?
`import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;`

Comment: driver instantiation would not have happened without these imports.....

Comment: Try to reproduce the same problem on a brand new empty project. Add the references to the Selenium files, and try again.

Comment: On a new project it works fine. What is the reason for this? I want it to be working on old project as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem. I was migrating scripts from RC to WebDriver and included both RC and Webdriver Java jars in the build path. Once i removed the RC files, it started working fine.

Thanks Arran, HemChe for atleast responding. Some ignorant fellow has rated my post -1 rating.