# Unable to use until method

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to wait for some element in Selenium Webdriver and following happens

I create wait:

```
WebDriverWait delay = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
```

And then use it:

```
delay.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("someId")));
```

But IntelliJ Idea keeps marking until() red and saying "Cannot resolve method until()".
Need help, please.

Comment: Have you imported `ExpectedConditions`?

Answer (score 0):

Change from `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("someId")));`

to

`delay.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("someId")));`

Also refer to selenium documentation, it has a good example on explicit wait- http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits

Comment: Sorry about that, i just mistyped. it's delay everywhere.

Comment: I copy WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("myDynamicElement"))); line from example and until() is still marked red.

Comment: Remove all jars and add again. sometimes it get corrupted.

Comment: See this post, this might be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16939260/driver-manage-timeouts-is-not-available