# I am getting error "The method timeouts() is undefined for the type WebDriver.Options"

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, testng-eclipse

I am using my implicit wait as below:

```
//import
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

//driver declaration
public static WebDriver driver = null;


//implicit wait
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

having error as below:

```
The method timeouts() is undefined for the type WebDriver.Options
```

Need help to resolve this.

Comment: What is your version of **selenium**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Driver.manage().timeouts() is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16939260/driver-manage-timeouts-is-not-available). It appears other people have this issue when they are accidentally using the wrong libraries for **selenium**. Double check to make sure you're compiling the correct libraries. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Nice catch. Seems to me a **Bug** with **`Selenium JARS`**

Here is the Answer to your Question:

As of now your code have only 2 lines. The first line `public static WebDriver driver = null;` shows no error as you have **`imported`** `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;`

In the second line , you are providing `Implicit Wait` as in `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`. In this case the IDE on which you are working tries to resolve the method `timeouts()` from `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver` which we have already imported. Hence no error should have been shown for `timeouts()` method.

[image: timeouts()_error]

Hence the following error is not justified:

```
The method timeouts() is undefined for the type WebDriver.Options
```

The error should have been shown for either `implicitlyWait()` method or parameter `TimeUnit`.

Now, the actual error is with the parameter `TimeUnit` which is passed within `implicitlyWait()` method. The IDE clearly suggests about importing `java.util.concurrent`.

[image: java.util.concurrent]

### Solution:

The solution is to import `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;` and your code will be error free as follows:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: I tried that already while troubleshooting. Still doesn't work. I am wondering it could be related with Selenium jars. But not sure which jars i should have to use